# Default value for application.properties (profile) environment placeholder cannot be comma separated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following property in my application.properties.

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,local
```

This works fine. However, I decided to also expose this as an environment variable and keep `dev,local` as the default values. However the following does not work.

```
spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES_ACTIVE:dev,local}
```

It seems comma causes this issue.

Checking the logs

```
[2018-05-24 05:38:28.163] [main] [INFO] [Application] The following profiles are active: ${PROFILES_ACTIVE:dev,local}
```

However, the following works.

```
spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES_ACTIVE:dev}
```

Any suggestions on how go about this?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Please [edit] your question and copy/paste the complete message and/or stack trace (format as code).

Comment: I am not getting a stacktrace error however I noticed that profile becomes `${PROFILES_ACTIVE:dev,local}` instead of `dev,local` . I will be editing the question to include this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES_ACTIVE:#{'dev,local'}}
```

It uses the EL [syntax](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-ref-literal) with [templating](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-templating).

Comment: This didn't work. Now log says `The following profiles are active: #{'dev,local'}`

Comment: something is not configured for the SpEL... Just for the sake of the argument, can you try `spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES_ACTIVE:'dev,local'}`

Comment: how to do it for boolean : 
server.ssl.enabled

Comment: server.ssl.enabled=${SSL_ENABLED:false} worked :)